# how to save the image in gallery that is captured by EXPO-CAMERA

Tags: react-native, expo

i have the local url of the imgae captured by expo-camera.
how to download or save this image?

url temporarily stored into "setCapturedPhoto" constant. but i want to store that image permanently into galley or anywhere inside my storage.

Comment: react-native-fs can do

Answer (score 0):

If you have an expo managed project, "react-native-fs" wont work.
You need something like expo-media-library. There is the documentation:

> https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/media-library/

The media library gives you an async function to store the photo with its photo.uri in the gallery.

you could use something like: `await MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync(photo.uri)`